# Typescript Generics: string converts into number and gives correct output

Tags: typescript, generics

```
function multi <T> (num: T): T {

    let total = num * 3; 
    return total; 
}

let amazing = multi<string>("3");
// or let amazing = multi("3");
// in both cases, I get output number 9.. why?
```

Questions:

1. Why Typescript converts explicit  type into number and
   gives output in number 9?
2. Why Typescript doesn't throw any error when I use string "3" and give me output in number 9 (in second case,in comment)?

Comment: Which version of TS do you use? 3.9.2 shows warnings both on `num * 3` line (The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type) and on `return total` (Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number'.)

Comment: I use typescript version 3.8.3

Comment: Well, it works the same in 3.8.3. Have you checked the error log in your setup when trying to compile this?

Comment: As a sidenote, I don't really see how you're going to use generic in this particular case. I mean, `*` requires casting to a set type, and that kinda contradicts the purpose of generics.

Comment: Learning Generics and Typescript on my own. My brain doesn't get me some satisfactory answers on how string can be multiplied with number and gets correct output in Typescript.  I don't really look at VS code error note as long as my program is compiling fine. 
Thanks.

Comment: I see. It's ideology of TS to be non-obstructive by default, but that can be changed; I suggest checking [this part](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#Strict_Type_Checking_Options_6173) of tutorial for details

Comment: This example is for learning purposes only. Also show me if I am making any other programming mistakes here. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not compile in typescript, but would work perfectly fine in compiled javascript ignoring typescript compiling error: javascript converts `num` to number before `*` operator.